# How to get a vertical geom_vline to an x-axis of class date?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, time-series

Even though I found Hadley's post in the google group on `POSIXct` and `geom_vline`, I could not get it done. I have a time series from and would like to draw a vertical line for years 1998, 2005 and 2010 for example. I tried with `ggplot` and `qplot` syntax, but still I either see no vertical line at all or the vertical line is drawn at the very first vertical grid and the whole series is shifted somewhat strangely to the right.

```
gg <- ggplot(data=mydata,aes(y=somevalues,x=datefield,color=category)) +
      layer(geom="line")
gg + geom_vline(xintercept=mydata$datefield[120],linetype=4)
# returns just the time series plot I had before, 
# interestingly the legend contains dotted vertical lines
```

My date field has format "1993-07-01" and is of class `Date`.

Comment: Can you add a few rows of your dataframe, so that we can try your example?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Try `as.numeric(mydata$datefield[120])`:

```
gg + geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(mydata$datefield[120]), linetype=4)
```

A simple test example:

```
library("ggplot2")

tmp <- data.frame(x=rep(seq(as.Date(0, origin="1970-01-01"),
                            length=36, by="1 month"), 2),
                  y=rnorm(72),
                  category=gl(2,36))

p <- ggplot(tmp, aes(x, y, colour=category)) +
     geom_line() +
     geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(tmp$x[c(13, 24)]),
                linetype=4, colour="black")
print(p)
```

[image: geom_vline example plot]

Comment: I found the 'as.numeric()' actually quite hard to find! Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if `geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.numeric(x[c(13, 24)])),
                linetype=4, colour="black")` would be more idiomatic, i.e., using `aes` instead of `tmp$`.

Comment: This solution no longer works. Code produces ```Error: Attempted to create layer with no stat.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.``'

Answer (score 57):

You could also do `geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date("2015-01-01")), linetype=4)` if you want the line to stay in place whether or not your date is in the 120th row.

Comment: on my machine (Win10 with R 3.2.2 and ggplot 1.0.1), I have to coerce the date to POSIXct to get it to align properly:  `as.POSIXct(as.Date(c("2016-12-01","2017-02-01")))`

Comment: Thank you Jthorpe.. this is the only version that worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Depending on how you pass your "Dates" column to `aes`, either `as.numeric` or `as.POSIXct` works:

`library(ggplot2)`

1. using `aes(as.Date(Dates),...)`

   ```
   ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(Dates), value)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date("2020-11-20")), 
                 color = "red", 
                 lwd = 2)
   ```
2. using `aes(Dates, ...)`

   ```
   ggplot(df, aes(Dates, value)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_vline(xintercept = as.POSIXct(as.Date("2020-11-20")), 
                 color = "red", 
                 lwd = 2)
   ```

Answer (score 4):

`as.numeric` works to me

```
ggplot(data=bmelt)+
  geom_line(aes(x=day,y=value,colour=type),size=0.9)+
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Observed","Counterfactual"),values = c("1","2"))+
  geom_ribbon(data=ita3,aes(x=day, 
      y=expcumresponse, ymin=exp.cr.ll,ymax=exp.cr.uu),alpha=0.2) +
  labs(title="Italy Confirmed cases",
        y ="# Cases ", x = "Date",color="Output")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(ymd("2020-03-13")), linetype="dashed", 
                color = "blue", size=1.5)+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]