# Adding multiple vlines for different dates in timeseries data

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, timeserieschart

I'm trying to plot a line chart with multiple time series data, where each line shows the sales trends over time for for a specific object - within the same start date and end date. My dataset is already in a "melted" form and looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   468 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date                : Date, format: "2019-04-11" "2019-04-12" "2019-04-13" ...
 $ Object                : chr  "Object1" "Object2" "Object3" "Object 4" ...
 $ daily_sales: int  1 257 178 177 255 240 231 214 193 174 ...
```

I have a set of dates for which I need vertical lines, and they're stored in a Date array, `imp.dates`

When I try to plot a single `vline` it works fine (with the following code):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=date,
               y=daily_sales,
               colour=Object,
               group=Object)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=imp.dates[1]),
            linetype=4,
            colour="black")
```

However, when I try to do multiple `vlines`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=date,
                   y=daily_sales,
                   colour=Object,
                   group=Object)) +
      geom_line() + 
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=imp.dates),
                linetype=4,
                colour="black")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (40): xintercept
```

The following are SO posts that I've looked at to no avail:
1. [Multiple vlines in plot gives error, ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092998/multiple-vlines-in-plot-gives-error-ggplot2)
2. [ggplot2: how to add text to multiple vertical lines (geom_vlines) on a time x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231903/ggplot2-how-to-add-text-to-multiple-vertical-lines-geom-vlines-on-a-time-x-ax)
3. [How to get a vertical geom_vline to an x-axis of class date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388832/how-to-get-a-vertical-geom-vline-to-an-x-axis-of-class-date)

3 comes very close, but my `x` variable is of class `Date` and not `int`, so can't seem to get it to work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put `imp.dates` into a data frame and change the data for the `geom_vline()` layer.

Here is some example data:

```
set.seed(2867)
df <- expand.grid(date = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = 1L),
                  object = paste0("object", 1:4))
df <- transform(df, daily_sales = rpois(nrow(df), lambda = 100))

set.seed(1)
imp <- data.frame(date = sample(unique(df$date), 4))
```

Here I just selected randomly 4 dates from the series as the important ones, you could do:

```
imp <- data.frame(date = imp.dates)
```

It is helpful to have the second data frame use the same variable name `date` but I don't believe this is necessary, just helpful/easier to parse in your head.

Now we build up the plot as you had it (note I changed `Object` to `object` in my code)

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = daily_sales, colour = object, group = object)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_vline(data = imp,               ## 1
             aes(xintercept = date),   ## 2
             linetype = 4, colour = "black")
```

Note that in line `##1` where we add the `geom_vline()` layer, we set the `data` argument for the layer to be our data frame of important dates, `imp`. In line `## 2` we specify the name of the variable in `imp` that contains the dates we want to draw. The rest of the plotting code is just as you had it.

This produces (a mess, it's random data):

[image]

but it now includes the 4 selected important dates represented as vertical lines.

Comment: Worked like a charm!