# Plotting geom_vline() on factorized x-axis

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, x-axis, vline

---

**Update**

I managed to get the vline to show by doing as @danlooo suggested,

```
geom_vline(aes(xintercept= 4.7) # 4.7 is the rough position of the first value in VLineValues <- c(25, 26, 27), between level 12 & 40 (also position 4 and 5)
```

However, since I have a lot of plots in my real data that are generated in a loop with 3 different vlines it's hard to find a formula to get the position right for all of the vlines.

Therefore I then tried to add a secondary axis with `sec.axis = sec_axis()` .
Unfortunately you can't add a continuous axis to a discrete on, you'll get the following error

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Then I tried to plot the data with a contous axis and add the factorized one as the secondary. However that "squeezes" the graph together which makes it loose it characteristic S-shape.

So I eventually just gave up on making these particular plots with ggplot, and instead just used the "normal" `plot()` function, which works great even-though it doesn't look as great as the ggplots....

---

I'm trying to add a vertical line to a ggplot with a factorized x-axis (it has to be factorized)using geom_vline. However the line does not show up.

I have tried several suggested solutions from:

[Positioning geom_vline with dates on x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661124/positioning-geom-vline-with-dates-on-x-axis)

[Draw geom_vline in discrete x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870284/draw-geom-vline-in-discrete-x-axis)

[ggplot geom_vline on x-axis of class date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288490/ggplot-geom-vline-on-x-axis-of-class-date)

https://www.py4u.net/discuss/866042 (this solution is for python...)

https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3197

https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4285

https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-add-a-vertical-line-on-a-factor/38341

[Issue with a drawing a vertical line in ggplot for categorical variable x-axis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149752/issue-with-a-drawing-a-vertical-line-in-ggplot-for-categorical-variable-x-axis-i)

This is an example of my current code:

```
library(drc)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

con <-  c(0,1,4,12,40,100,300,1000, 0,1,4,12,40,100,300,1000,0,1,4,12,40,100,300,1000)
Vector <- c(1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2, 2.7, 3, 3.5, 4,1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2, 2.7, 3, 3.5, 4,1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2, 2.7, 3, 3.5, 4)
df <- data.frame(Vector, con)

VLineValues <- c(25, 26, 27)

  dfTemp <- df[1:8,]
  dfTemp$X = con[1:8]
  dfTemp$X <- factor(dfTemp$X, levels=unique(dfTemp$X))
  
  print(ggplot(dfTemp, aes(x = X, y = Vector))+
        ylim(1, 4.5)+
        geom_point()+
        geom_vline(aes(xintercept= VLineValues[1] )+
        geom_smooth(method = drm, method.args = list(fct = LL.5()), se = FALSE))
```

What I want to do is to loop over the df, get 3 separate plots with one line each at x = 25, x=26 & x=27.

As I mentioned above I've tried some other solutions where you get the position of the levels, mutate? the data with tidyverse and so forth.

The Vline shows up fine if the x-axis is numeric or if I for example write

```
geom_vline(1:5) #Gives Vlines at the 5 first levels in the factorised x-axis
```

However, it does not show up between the levels on the factorised x-axis

Any suggestions on how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

A factor can only consist of values within given levels:

```
> dfTemp$X
[1] 0    1    4    12   40   100  300  1000
Levels: 0 1 4 12 40 100 300 1000
```

None of your x intercept values (25, 26, 27) are within the levels thus one can not plot the vertical lines.

`xintercept` can be set using either the string or the position of the levels:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <-
  iris %>%
  mutate(Species = Species %>% as.factor())

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 2) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = "setosa")

levels(data$Species)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So if I understand it correctly it isn't possible to add xintercept between the levels?
In the provided example the xintercept is either at the setosa level (position 1) or at position 2 (versicolor level)

Comment: That is the nature of factors: They are discrete. Only in continuous scales like (real) numbers you can always put another number in between.

Comment: Ah, too bad, was not aware of that...
Great suggestion with the secondary x-axis! I'll try that, thanks