# geom_vline to indicate today's date in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Would love to display a `vline` that indicates today's date in `ggplot2`.

Here's what i'm trying. It doesn't break the visual, but it also doesn't work.

```
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = as.integer(dataset$Today)), col = "black") +
```

in my dataset (an .xls) I have a column named "Today" where I used the function `=today()` (which works btw) so I'm just trying to grab that & display it as a `vline`.

As a side note this works perfectly well:

```
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = as.integer(as.POSIXct("2017-07-18"))), col = "black") +
```

---

Here's the whole shebang:

```
library(scales) #date time scales  
library(ggplot2) # Visualization  


#Convert timestamp to POSIXct.

dataset$From<-as.POSIXct(dataset$From,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
dataset$To<-as.POSIXct(dataset$To,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")

#ggplot stuff

ggplot(dataset,aes(x=datetime_start, y=dataset$Product, color=Stage, order = - as.numeric(Stage))) +
scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels=date_format("%b%y")) +
geom_segment(aes(x=From,xend=To,yend=dataset$Product),size=15) +

#Custom V Line

geom_vline(aes(xintercept = as.integer(as.POSIXct("2017-07-18"))), col = "black") +

#Custom Legend Ordering

scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set3", breaks=c("CPR","PPR","DPR", "VPR/IPR", "GA")) +

#Title

ggtitle("Product Phase Review Schedule") + xlab("") + ylab("") + theme_bw()
```

Comment: Is the trailing `+` a typo, or should there be more code?

Comment: `ggplot(data.frame(date = seq(Sys.Date() - 5, Sys.Date() + 5, by = 'day')), aes(date, date)) + geom_point() + geom_vline(xintercept = Sys.Date())`

Comment: @Juan there's more code, it's just not relevant.

Comment: @alistaire hmm that broke my visual. I posted the entirety of my code to show you in context. Ta!

Comment: Try `as.numeric()` instead of `as.integer()`. See that link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388832/how-to-get-a-vertical-geom-vline-to-an-x-axis-of-class-date

Comment: @PaulEndymion thank you, `as.numeric` works, but doesn't change my success with `dataset$Today`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()))), col = "black") +
```

`as.integer` worked too