# Merging separate Month and Year columns to graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I've been around the forums looking for a solution to my issue but can't seem to find anything. Derivatives of my question and their answer haven't really helped either. My data has four columns, one for Year and one for Month). I've been wanting to plot the data all in one graph without using any facets for years in ggplot. This is what I've been struggling with so far with:

```
df<-data.frame(Month = rep(c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                         "July", "August", "September", "October", 
                         "November", "February", "March"),each = 20), 
           Year = rep(c("2018", "2019"), times = c(220, 40)), 
                      Type = rep(c("C", "T"), 260), 
                                 Value = runif(260, min = 10, max = 55))
df$Month<-ordered(df$Month, month.name)
df$Year<-ordered(df$Year)
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Month, y = Value, fill = Type)) +
  facet_wrap(~Year)
```

I'd ideally like to manage this using dplyr and lubridate. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to make a true date value, then you can use the date axis formatter. Something like this is a rough start

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = lubridate::mdy(paste(Month, 1, Year)), y = Value, fill = Type, group=lubridate::mdy(paste(Month, 1, Year)))) + 
  scale_x_date(breaks="month", date_labels = "%m")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @MrFlick Thanks for the quick response I think that could work. Any ideas on how you would add vertical lines between those months especially when the x-axis is on a date class scale?

Comment: @LeoOhyama you mean like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388832/how-to-get-a-vertical-geom-vline-to-an-x-axis-of-class-date

Comment: exactly! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey @MrFlick . I just got one more question. Your answer specified the fill aesthetic as for the Variable "type" but the graph still doesn't show this fill.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
 df<-data.frame(Month = rep(c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                             "July", "August", "September", "October", 
                             "November", "February", "March"),each = 20), 
               Year = rep(c("2018", "2019"), times = c(220, 40)), 
               Type = rep(c("C", "T"), 260), 
               Value = runif(260, min = 10, max = 55))
df$Month <- factor(df$Month,levels=c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                             "July", "August", "September", "October", 
                                  "November", "Dicember"), ordered = T)
df$Month<-ordered(df$Month)
df$Year<-ordered(df$Year)
df$Year_Month <- paste0(df$Month, " ", df$Year)

df$Year_Month <- factor(df$Year_Month, levels = unique(df$Year_Month))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = Year_Month, y = Value, fill = Type))
```

[image]